# set all negative -1 values into 0 on table load

Tags: jquery, html

When the table is loaded i want to set all the values of -1 to 0...
I tried the code below but it is not working.

added the snippet, even with the suggestions is not working...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("bothSexes");
  $('#error-ageGroup tbody').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var bothSexes = row.find(".bothSexesError2").val();
    alert(bothSexes);
    var femaleErorr = row.find(".femaleSexesError2").val();
    var MaleError = row.find(".maleSexesError2").val();
    if (bothSexes === -1) {
      row.find(".bothSexesError2").val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="error-ageGroup" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
  <thead class="heading">
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Age Group</th>
      <th class="centerTD">Both Sex</th>
      <th class="centerTD">Male Count</th>
      <th class="centerTD">Female Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="whitebg">
    <tr>
      <td class='bothSexesError bothSexesError2'>
        <input class="centerTD" name="bothSexesError" type="text" value="-1" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td class='maleSexesError maleSexesError2'>
        <input class="centerTD" name="maleError" type="text" value=" -1" />
      </td>
      <td class='femaleSexesError femaleSexesError2'>
        <input class="centerTD" name="femaleError" type="text" value="-1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `val()` returns a string, yet you are comparing it to an integer. You need to either convert both to the same data type:

```
if (parseInt(bothSexes, 10) === -1) { // or (bothSexes === "-1")
    row.find("#bothSexesError").val(0);
}
```

Or use a type-insensitive comparison, where the types are automatically coerced to match:

```
if (bothSexes == -1) { // note '=='. The string will be coerced to a Number for you
    row.find("#bothSexesError").val(0);
}
```

Personally I'd use the former as the latter can occasionally lead to unexpected results.

*Update*

Now that you've added your HTML I can see that there's several issues here.

- You have duplicated `id` attributes. You should change them to classes or remove them entirely if they aren't needed.
- Your code is in a `load()` event handler, which is redundant as you already run in a `document.ready` handler, and the element is not an `img`, `iframe` etc.
- You have additional space around the value which can have an effect depending on which comparison method I mentioned above you use. Remove the spaces.

Here's a working example with all the above fixes in place:

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3hxsvwab/)

Comment: Uh oh, so much lengthy `parseInt()`? Why not just `~bothSexes`?

Comment: oh yeah, did not see that but it doesnt even enter the `alert("bothSexes");` ?

Comment: the problem now, the code is fired.. even when the table is not loaded so there is an undefined value.. alert, the second alert

Comment: Now you've added your HTML I can see you've repeated the same `id` attribute throughout all the inputs in your loop. You need to convert them to classes as your code is invalid at the moment

Comment: nope it does not change anything... but noted. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I updated my answer for you as there were several other problems.

Comment: `$('input').val((_,v) => +v === -1 ? 0 : v);`